# how to select top N in access report detail section or select top N in sql subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2010

I have a report that is based on a query. In the detail section of the report I want to limit the number of detail lines to top N. (like  a select TOP N type query). In this sample I want the top 2 rows. Query I have so far is

```
 SELECT TestTable.[GroupByCol], TestTable.[DetailColA]
 FROM TestTable group by TestTable.[GroupByCol], TestTable.[DetailColA]
```

I know I need to join and do some having and count but it's just not clicking. I have also attached a screenshot.

Please advise. thank you
[image]

Comment: You need to specify an `ORDER BY`, otherwise your "TOP 2" makes no sense as that could be random.

Comment: @cularis. Yes. It is now clear from mwolfe02's answer below. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query as your report recordsource:

```
SELECT  TestTable.GroupByCol, TestTable.DetailColA
FROM TestTable 
WHERE TestTable.DetailColA IN 
  (SELECT TOP 2 DetailColA FROM TestTable AS TT 
   WHERE TT.GroupByCol=TestTable.GroupByCol 
   ORDER BY TT.DetailColA) 
ORDER BY TestTable.GroupByCol, TestTable.DetailColA
```

See Allen Browne's [Subquery Basics](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html) for more information.

---

EDIT: As you alluded to in your comment, this can also be written as follows:

```
SELECT a.GroupByCol, a.DetailColA, COUNT(*) As RankNumber
FROM TestTable AS a INNER JOIN TestTable AS b
  ON a.GroupByCol = b.GroupByCol
 AND a.DetailColA >= b.DetailColA
GROUP BY a.GroupByCol, a.DetailColA
HAVING COUNT(*)<=2
ORDER BY a.GroupByCol, a.DetailColA, COUNT(*)
```

You would have to benchmark to be sure, but this second version is probably more efficient.  Which is more readable is probably a matter of personal preference (I find the first version more intuitive and readable).

Comment: thx @mwolfe02. This should work. Will test and update tomorrow. Is there another way to write this query using having clause ? Actually i got confused from this question which is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481916/access-top-n-in-group