# Top 5 Select Statement by Column

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I'm looking to get the Top 5 barcodes by Title to show the most recent comic books that came out for each Title (the calculations show how many we've sold to pull list customers and walk-ups)... currently if I leave TOP 5 in the SELECT statement it only shows the Top 5 highest barcodes in the system.

I'm sorry in advance for the bad coding below :(  Thank you in advance for being nice ;)

```
SELECT TOP 5 tblInventory.barcode, tblInventory.[Issue#], tblInventory.Title, Nz([qryLast_PullList].[SumOfQuantity],0) AS PullList, Nz([qryLast_WalkUp].[SumOfQuantity],0) AS WalkUp, Nz([qryLast_PullList].[SumOfQuantity],0)+Nz([qryLast_WalkUp].[SumOfQuantity],0) AS Total
FROM (tblInventory LEFT JOIN qryLast_PullList ON tblInventory.ID = qryLast_PullList.ID) LEFT JOIN qryLast_WalkUp ON tblInventory.ID = qryLast_WalkUp.ID
GROUP BY tblInventory.barcode, tblInventory.[Issue#], tblInventory.Title, Nz([qryLast_PullList].[SumOfQuantity],0), Nz([qryLast_WalkUp].[SumOfQuantity],0), Nz([qryLast_PullList].[SumOfQuantity],0)+Nz([qryLast_WalkUp].[SumOfQuantity],0)
ORDER BY tblInventory.barcode DESC;
```

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access top n in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481916/access-top-n-in-group)

Comment: Thanks @June7 - looks like both of those will point me in the right direction!!  I'll give 'em a shot tomorrow!!