# SQL - Tricky Merging

Tags: sql, merge

I'm facing a tricky query to do. I hope your expertise will help me to sort it out.

There are 2 tables:

Table1 : Orders

```
Index                 ProductName             OrderDate
0                      a                      03/03/1903
1                      a                      10/03/2014
2                      b                      01/01/2017
3                      c                      01/01/2019
```

Table2 : Product Specs 
--> This table shows every change made in the Color of our products

```
Index         ProductName                    Color   ColorUpdatedOn
0                      a                     Blue     01/01/1900
1                      a                     Red      01/01/2014
2                      a                     Yellow   01/01/2017
3                      b                     Pink     01/01/2017
4                      c                     Black    01/01/2018
5                      c                     Black    31/12/2018
```

I would like to be able to retrieve all the data from Table1 with the Column Color et UpdatedOn

```
Index   ProductName    OrderDate          Color   ColorUpdatedOn
0        a           03/03/1903           Blue     01/01/1900
1        a           10/03/2014           Red      01/01/2014
2        a           01/01/2019           Yellow   01/01/2017    
3        c           01/01/2019           Black    31/12/2018
```

Do you have any idea how I could do this ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Largo

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Looks like basic JOIN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access top n in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481916/access-top-n-in-group)

Answer (score 0):

Get the `max()` date of `Product Specs` table based on color,
then `join` it using `year()` function, applicable on `mysql` and `mssql`, not sure with other db.

```
select o.Index, o.ProdcutName, o.Date, t1.color, t1.ColorUpdatedOn
from Orders o
inner join
    (select color, max(colorupdatedon) as ColorUpdatedOn 
    from productspecs
    group by color) t1 on year(o.OrderDate) = year(t1.createdon)
```

but I would prefer using `right()` function since your year dates are at the end.

```
select o.Index, o.ProdcutName, o.Date, t1.color, t1.ColorUpdatedOn
    from Orders o
    inner join
        (select color, max(colorupdatedon) as ColorUpdatedOn 
        from productspecs
        group by color) t1 on right(o.OrderDate, 4) = right(t1.createdon, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the datatype for `OrderDate` and `ColorUpdatedOn` are both `date`, we can find the colors which was at the time of order.
For this I have used the anlytical/windowing function. The `Hive` query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    y.ProductName, y.OrderDate, y.Color, y.ColorUpdatedOn
FROM (
    SELECT 
        x.*,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY x.ProductName, x.OrderDate ORDER BY x.recency ASC) AS relevance
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            a.*, b.color, b.ColorUpdatedOn, DATEDIFF(a.OrderDate, b.ColorUpdatedOn) AS recency
        FROM 
            Order a 
        INNER JOIN 
            Product b 
        ON (
            a.ProductName = b.ProductName
            AND a.OrderDate >= b.ColorUpdatedOn
        )
    ) x 
) y
WHERE 
    y.relevance = 1;
```

The query could be made specific if you let me know the database you are using.
Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In a database that supports lateral joins (which is quite a few of them now), this is pretty easy:

```
select o.*, s.*  -- select the columns you want
from orders o left join lateral
     (select s.*
      from specs s
      where s.ProductName = o.ProductName and
            s.ColorUpdatedOn <= o.OrderDate 
      order by s.ColorUpdatedOn desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) s
     on 1=1;
```

In SQL Server, this would use `outer apply` rather than `left join lateral`.

In other databases, I would use `lead()`:

```
select o.*, s.*  -- select the columns you want
from orders o left join
     (select s.*,
             lead(ColorUpdatedOn) over (partition by ProductName order by ColorUpdatedOn) as next_ColorUpdatedOn
      from specs s
     ) s
     on s.ProductName = o.ProductName and
        o.OrderDate >= s.ColorUpdatedOn and
        (o.OrderDate < s.next_ColorUpdatedOn or s.next_ColorUpdatedOn is null)
```